# Can't index a dict in a list comprehension

Tags: dictionary, scikit-learn, list-comprehension, python-3.5

I'm attempting to extract a `list` from a `list` of `dict`s.
Each `dict` in the list has a single key-value mapping. I want to create a `list` of that single value mapped in each `dict` contained by the `list`.

See below the code and output, written in an interactive form.

```
>>> print(str(param_to_outputs_dict_dict))
{('max_features', 1558): {'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=1558, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}, 
('max_features', 7713): {'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=7713, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
>>> print()
```

Above we see that `param_to_outputs_dict_dict` is a `dict` of two entries. The key for each entry is a `tuple` and the value is a `dict`.

Next, I use list comprehension to extract the `list` of values (of type `dict`)

```
>>> map_list = [output_dict for output_dict in list(param_to_outputs_dict_dict.values())]
>>> print(str(map_list))
[{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=1558, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}, 
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=7713, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}]
>>> print()
```

We see that this worked, also. We have a `list` containing two `dict`s, which were the values contained in `param_to_outputs_dict_dict`.

Now, instead of extracting the dictionaries, I instead attempt to extract the value in each dictionary mapped by the value `'classifier'`.

```
>>> classifier_list = [output_dict['classifier'] for output_dict in list(param_to_outputs_dict_dict.values())]
>>> print(str(classifier_list))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-b6f236339c69> in <module>()
      8 print(str(map_list))
      9 print()
---> 10 classifier_list = [output_dict['classifier'] for output_dict in list(param_to_outputs_dict_dict.values())]
     11 print(str(classifier_list))
     12 print()

<ipython-input-176-b6f236339c69> in <listcomp>(.0)
      8 print(str(map_list))
      9 print()
---> 10 classifier_list = [output_dict['classifier'] for output_dict in list(param_to_outputs_dict_dict.values())]
     11 print(str(classifier_list))
     12 print()
TypeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object is not subscriptable
```

However, this does not work. The error message leads me to think that Python interpreted `output_dict` as being of type `DecisionTreeClassifier`, but I have no idea why. I've played with this problem for hours but am completely stumped.

I suspect the solution may be extremely obvious to someone else! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: critical information missing from original post**

To make the question shorter and cleaner, I had truncated the printing results to only include the first two elements of any collection. However, after realising the problem (see my answer below), the cause of the problem is extremely obvious when the full list is given. See below, notably the last element of the list.

```
>>> for value in list(param_to_outputs_dict_dict.values()):
>>>     print(str(value))
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=10,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=100,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=-100, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=3, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=-10000, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=7791, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=77, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=100000,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=1558, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=1,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=3895, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=7713, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=7011, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced', criterion='gini',
        max_depth=None, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
        splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='random')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=-1000, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=779, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=10000,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=-1, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=1000, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=1000,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10000, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=6232, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=100, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='entropy', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=88, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=-10, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=100000, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
{'classifier': DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=-100000, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')}
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

Comment: I personally can't see anything wrong with it.  I don't know what your DecisionTreeClassifier class looks like, but with this fake one I made up, it seems to run fine:   http://ideone.com/uzNw17

Comment: @DavidWhite thanks for running that for me. Hmm, this is perplexing! FYI I'm using sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier from scikit-learn in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the full list printed in the question, we can see that the last element is not of type `dict` containing a single `str` to `DecisionTreeClassifier` mapping, but is instead simply of type `DecisionTreeClassifier`.

Thus, the following code:

```
[output_dict['classifier'] for output_dict in list(param_to_outputs_dict_dict.values())]
```

which assigns each element of `list(param_to_outputs_dict_dict.values())` to `output_dict` assigns a `DecisionTreeClassifier` at the last element.

Therefore, on that iteration, the statement `output_dict['classifier']` attempts to subscript a `DecisionTreeClassifier` object, **not** a `dict`. This yields the `TypeError` given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a number of redundant things. The following is the way to do it.

```
[v["classifier"] for v in param_to_outputs_dict_dict.values()]
```

`list(dict.values())` and `[v for v in dict.values()]` are the same thing, then what is the semantic justification for `[v for v in list(dict.values())]`. On the same line, what exactly is `print(str(x))`? `print(x)` outputs the `x.__str__()`. Thats what I meant when I said redundant.

Comment: In Python 3, dict.values() returns a view, rather than a list. That view is not indexable, and will change if the underlying dict changes. Thus, your implementation is less thread-safe.

Comment: Also, I prefer to explicitly cast data; it looks clearer to me to say `str(x)` (the string representation of `x`) rather than passing a non-string type into `print` and relying on it to read my mind.